# log4net Package Dependency Issues - Version 2.0.9.0 and 2.0.12.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I've got a problem after I added the Logz.io log4net plugin (`Logzio.DotNet.Log4net`) to my .NET project:

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find type [log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json]
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'log4net, Version=2.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepalive)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)


log4net:ERROR Failed to create object to set param: layout
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [LogzioAppender] of type [Logzio.DotNet.Log4net.LogzioAppender, Logzio.DotNet.Log4net]. Reported error follows.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'log4net, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepalive)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
```

In short, `[log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json]` is requesting log4net version `2.0.9.0`, while `[Logzio.DotNet.Log4net.LogzioAppender, Logzio.DotNet.Log4net]` is requesting log4net version `2.0.12.0`

So in this case I understand the problem clearly, but don't know how to resolve it. I've never seen this before, usually, NuGet does a good job by itself.

Ideally, it'd be great to get both to use log4net `2.0.13.0`, which is the latest version at the time of this post, but I'd be happy learning how I can resolve this issue in general.

Any ideas or solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Updating to the latest version will resolve the issue as the minimum has been required log4net version `2.0.12.0` when the backward compatibility has not been entertained by Logz.io.

A few days back I also had faced alike issues while most of the packages are updating after the ms vs 2022 final release!

Comment: Indeed this seems to be one of the issues! Though I think it was even more complicated by the fact I had a mixed-up version of `log4net.Ext.Json`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out of course minutes after posting. The trick *was* to trust in NuGet. Somehow through my tinkering I got mixed up versions. So the solution was the following:

1. Right click solution -> `Manage NuGet Packages`
2. Uninstall `log4net`, `log4net.Ext.Json`, and `Logzio.DotNet.Log4net`
3. Reinstall all three. NuGet will take the latest compatible versions, which as @yasir-arafat mentioned, is needed to resolve the conflicts at least for the Logzio package. In the end, I can confirm the following configuration (from my `.csproj` file) is working:

```
<PackageReference Include="log4net.Ext.Json" Version="2.0.10.1" />
<PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Logzio.DotNet.Log4net" Version="1.0.13" />
```

Update: As mentioned below, this doesn't *always* work. I've tried with this `app.config` but it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.13.0" newVersion="2.0.12.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.1" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If I delete my docker container entirely and have no `app.config`, my project seems to build successfully.

I'm continuing to investigate.

Comment: Update: still investigating an active issue with this, I thought it was resolved but sometimes during builds it breaks, some package is requesting log4net version 2.0.9.0 I'll report back when I figure it out